# Суффиксы -и(с)т и -а(с)т

Tags: суффиксы, словообразование

Почему в одних случаях "-с-" присутствует, а в других нет?

- Шипастый, лучистый?

Но:

- Рогатый, деловитый?

Теоретически:

- Шипатый (как сохатый, родовитый), лучитый
- Рогастый (как зубастый), деловистый (как шелковистый)

Answer (score 5):

Потому что у этих суффиксов [разные значения](http://wordsland.ru/magiclanguage/suff.html):

> *-ист-* — прилагательные со значением:
>
> - похожий на что-то (серебристый, бархатистый);
> - **обладающий чем-то в большом количестве (голосистый, ветвистый);**
> - имеющий склонность к какому-нибудь действию (задиристый, отрывистый, порывистый)

Шипастый — много шипов (растут по всей площади), лучистый — много лучей (по аналогии).

> *-ат-*/*-аст-* — прилагательные, называющих части тела человека или животного, внешних качеств человека, аксессуаров его внешности (волосатый, косматый, губастый, очкастый, рогатый, скуластый)

Рогатый — обладающий рогами как частью тела. *Можно* сказать «рогастый», [имея в виду](https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%A0/302) «имеющий особенно большие рога», по аналогии с *-аст-*. Однако значение «обладающий рогами *в большом количестве*» настолько образное и разговорное, [что даже в книгах не встречается](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=12).

> *-ит-*/*-овит-* — обладающий в бо́льшей степени чем-нибудь (именитый, ядовитый, сердитый)

Деловитый — не «дело в большом количестве», а «бо́льшая степень отношения к делу».

Comment: вопрос на самом деле заключается не в различии значений суффиксов, и в разнице между формами суффиксов одного типа **-атый** против **-астый**, и **-итый** против **-истый**, то есть в причине добавления согласной **[с]**

Comment: То есть не о причине применения конкретного суффикса в конкретном случае (почему здесь одно, а там другое)? Тогда да, мой ответ смысла не имеет. Но пока оставлю его, пусть автор рассудит.

Comment: Впечатление такое, что "рогатый" попало в этот ряд в таком виде и все. Ср. "мордатый и мордастый" - оба существуют в этом ряду.

Comment: да, мне нравится объяснение, но вопрос какое правило влияет на присутствие или отсутсвие "-с-".

Comment: @J.Doe Вы о смысловом правиле («при каких условиях вставляется») или историческом («присутствие или отсутствие именно „с“ в этом смысле, а не, скажем, „г“»)? На первый вопрос ответ дан в моём сообщении (это не грамматическое правило, а смысл, передаваемый суффиксом); на второй я ответа, увы, не знаю.